# Invariance w.r.t. $A$ implies invariance w.r.t. $\exp (tA)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reading through a text on linear differential equation where we look at the equation $$\dot x =Ax$$ and it says that *the stable and unstable subspaces are invariant with respect $A$ and therefore also with respect to $\exp (tA)$*.

What I'm confused about is: To which definition of "invariant set"  does the text refer to; does it refer to the definition saying that a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant w.r.t. the map $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ if $A(S)\subseteq S$ or does it refer to the definition of "invariant" which says that solutions starting in $S$ stay in $S$ for all future and past times as long as they exist ?

Once this is clear, could you please give me a hint, how to show the italic statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is meant and the statement follows directly from the definition of $\exp(tA)$:
$$\exp(tA) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!} (tA)^k$$
Wich is a linear combination of powers of $A$. Now if $A(S) \subset S$, so is $A^k(S) \subset S$.

Comment: But if $A(S)\subset S$, then it *doesn't* follow that $(tA)(S)\subset S$ - take for example $A$ as the identity in the plane and $S$ the line parallel to the $x$-axis going through $(0,1)$ and $t=2$.

Comment: The crucial part is that $S$ is a linear subspace. Your example is no linear subspace.