# Flow-Invariance w.r.t. $A$ doesn't invariance w.r.t. $\exp (tA)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046755/invariance-w-r-t-a-implies-invariance-w-r-t-exp-ta/1046759#1046759) answered question of mine explains that by saying *consider $$\dot x =Ax,$$ then the stable and unstable subspaces are invariant with respect $A$ and therefore also with respect to $\exp (tA)$* one means  the definition of "invariant set" saying that **a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant w.r.t. the map $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ if $A(S)\subseteq S$** - not the  definition of "invariant" saying that solutions starting in $S$ stay in $S$ for all future and past times as long as they exist!

My question is: So that I can understand this distinction better, could someone please provide me with a counterexample that shows that when one reads the italic statement using the second definition,the italic statement is false ?